# Rendering problem with AJAX in IE

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I am using Ajax, Jquery, PHP, MySQL to build an ad review site; 
Mysql holds data (publication, title, hits, etc.); 
PHP pulls the data and forms the HTML based on variables sent from JQuery AJAX;
(tested mac safari, ff, chrome. Win FF, Chrome)

All is good in every browser but IE 7 + 8...
- the issue is that the first result of the ajax call is cut off, showing only the bottom 2 lines... 
- tested without css and same result
- killed all superfluous code and same result
- I am forming the HTML on the server side...which works fine on the other browsers.

I am stumped- any help would be great

Comment: Either post code or a screenshot showing the 'cut off'

Comment: www.camdesigns.net/help Hope this helps, and thanks for your quick replies

Answer (score 0):

With IE specific issues it's almost always related to the margin and padding settings because of how IE (incorrectly) renders the box model.

Please post code, and we can get more specific.

Comment: I have removed all of the style sheets and still get the error

Comment: So, I downloaded IE9 and it works great there... what does IE7/8 not have?

Comment: So i created new functions that grab the height and with variables and used Jquery to generate the content vs. PHP *****Solved